# Redis: Efficient key sharding for large key set

Tags: algorithm, hash, redis, key

I have a problem where I am going beyond the amount of RAM in my server.  I need to reduce the database size so that I can still use Redis.  My application is a massive key / value store where the keys are user given text strings (directory / file paths).  The values are very simple pointers to objects that I create.  So it is an object store.  The problem is that I have a Petabyte of objects, where an object could be 100K bytes.  I can actually constrain the average object to be no less than 1M bytes, so 10^15 / 10^6 = 10^9 objects.  Being that each object needs a key, that is 10^9, or 1G keys.  If each key/value pair is 100 bytes, that is 100GB in RAM.  That almost fits in servers with 128GB of RAM but it is not the only thing that is going on in the server.  I'd like to reduce the footprint if I can.

The question is what direction to go in?  I tried compressing the input key, but that was actually bigger than the original in my testing because it is such a short string and not a document.  I have thought about using a different data store for smaller sized files, let's say below 1G.  That will reduce what I need to put into Redis.  I have also thought about using a hash algorithm that intentionally overlaps and bins the keys, and then putting the hash deltas into the merged keys as values.  If that it too confusing here is a made up example:

```
Key    Hash
A       15gh2
B       15gh2
C       4Tgnx
```

I would then store in Redis:
V(15gh2) = A, B, A-Value=A-Object, B-Value=B-Object

V(4Tgnx) = C

There is probably a proper way to algebraically represent this, but I don't know how to do that.  "A-Object" is my pointer to the A object.  What I'm trying to do is to end up with fewer keys, based on some posts I've read about keys being more expensive than Redis hash values (don't confuse the "Redis hash" with the "hash" algorithm).  I have access to http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ full database to search for papers on this topic.  I'm not quite sure what I should be searching for in the query field?  I tried things like "hash chain" but that appears to be targeting encryption more than efficient database stores. Any solution ideas or paths for greater research would be appreciated.

Update: As noted in the comments section, the values, or what I call "A-Object", "B-Object" are encoded "pointers" that are paths to objects.  These are actual files in an XFS filesystem.  They can be encoded as simply as "1:6:2" to point to path "/data/d0001/d0006/d0002".  So a very short value "1:6:2" is all that needs to be stored.

Comment: Without more details of what your KV pairs are I can only offer vague ideas.  The first thing I would think about is how the data in the object I point to is represented?  Do I actually need all the bytes I'm using there?  For example, am I using doubles when floats are sufficient? etc.  It seems like you'll get the most bang for your buck if you can reduce the size of the Value objects (or the size of the object pointed to).

Comment: The values are "ultimately" paths in another directory tree.  I say "ultimately" because I have total control over the layout, they just need to be one file per object in an XFS filesystem.  So the encoding can be very compact because I know the prefix of the path, it is just the unique identifier.  For example, I create a directory tree of very regular structure.  Let's say d0001/d0004/d0002 might be a "path" to an object.  But I can encode that as "1:4:2", for example as the value.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes that helps.  The thing I would then be careful of is that 1:4:2, are the 1, 4, and 2 stored as ints (4 or 8 bytes) or as a char (1 byte each)?  Then you just have to decide what you need (what range of values at each depth) and not use any extra bytes.  If the largest you could have is a d9999 -> 9999 then you certainly don't need an 8 byte int to store that, 2 bytes is enough.  If you don't have a 2 byte data type, you can either make one or reserve space in a 4 byte (or 8 byte) int: top 2 bytes = level 1, next 2 bytes = level 2, etc.  Perhaps you're already doing something of this flavor

Comment: Yes, good point.  I am currently not doing any optimization, I just started to work on this aspect.  So right now it is a string value and I just turn that into a path.  So I too was thinking of doing the most compact fixed bit integer representation for the value.  It is more the keys that has me stumped.

Comment: The other thing to think about is: do you need all those KV pairs in memory at the same time?  Or, could you generate 1GB of data for each CPU at a time, let each CPU do its processing, then when a CPU finishes, generate another 1GB for it?  Then you are only using #CPUs GB at any given time.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the keys? those are just short ints? I thought?  They should use very little of the total memory if your pair is using anywhere from 100B to 10KB, at most 2-4B of that is the key... unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  Redis is an in-memory store, but you may be talking about multiple instances of Redis?  Kind of a map-reduce operation? - The keys are user given strings.  I can hash them to get ints but that is not the starting point.

Comment: Sorry, I when I saw KV I was thinking of map-reduce.  My experience with that is limited to Spark and MapReduce-MPI.  I'm not terribly familiar with redis.  (I feel awful if I've led you astray.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach with this much data is to partition data across multiple servers.

See http://redis.io/topics/partitioning for advice on how to do that.